# Recursive functions for partitions, stirling numbers, and chebyshev polynomials of the first

Tags: c++, recursion, partitioning, partition

So I'm working on a homework assignment and I need to create recursive functions for partitions, Stirling numbers(first and second kind), and Chebyshev polynomials of the first. My program should be able to have a user input a positive integer n, and then create files named Partitions.txt, Stirling1.txt, Stirling2.txt, and Chebyshev.txt, that creates a table of all values f(k,m) for 1<=k<=n and 1<=m<=n. I'm struggling just to start off the assignment and feel like I have no understanding of it even though I've been doing research and trying to figure it out. If someone can help me out, I'd really appreciate it! Thank you!

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include "OutputFile.h"

    using namespace std;
    using namespace OutputStream;


    int firstKindStirling();
    vector<vector<int> > getPartitions(int number, int maxElement);

    int main() {

        cout << "Welcome! Please input a number m:";
        int m;
        cin>>m;


        OFile fout("Partitions.txt");

        return 0;
    }

    vector<vector<int> > getPartitions(int number, int maxElement)
    {
        if (number < 1) 
            return vector<vector<int>>();

       vector<vector<int>> partitions;

        if (number <= maxElement) 
            partitions.push_back(number); //for some reason this doesn't want to work. Not sure what I'm missing here. 

        for (int i = number - maxElement; i < number; ++i)
        {
            // (recursively) get the partitions of `i`, with elements no larger than `n - i`
            auto partitionsForI = getPartitions(i, number - i);

            // add `n - i` to the front of all of those partitions
            for(vector<int>& partition : partitionsForI)
            {
                partition.insert(partition.begin(), number - i);
            }

            // add these new partitions to our list.
            partitions.insert(partitions.end(), partitionsForI.begin(), partitionsForI.end());
        }
        return partitions;
    }

    int firstKindStirling(int n, int k) 
    {
        if (n == 0 && k == 0) return 1;
        else if (n == 0 || k == 0) return 0;
        else return -(n-1) * firstKindStirling(n-1, k) + firstKindStirling(n-1, k-1);
    }
```

And here's my Output .h file

```
    #ifndef OUTPUT_H
    #define OUTPUT_H

    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <memory>

    namespace OutputStream {

        class OFile {
            std::ofstream file;
        public:

            OFile(std::string filename, size_t output_precision = 10) {

                file.open(filename);
                if(file.fail()) throw std::runtime_error("Error: cannot open file");

                file.precision(output_precision);

            };

            /*
            OFile& operator<<(int x) {
                file<<x;
                return *this;
            }
            */

            /*
            OFile& operator<<(const Point2D& p) {
                file<<p;
                return *this;
            }
            */

            OFile& operator<<(const std::vector<int>& v) {

                for(auto x : v) file<<x<<std::endl;
                return *this;
            }


            template<typename T>
            OFile& operator<<(const T& p) {
                file << p;
                return *this;
            }


            ~OFile() { file.close(); };

        };


        // Strongly enumerate type
        enum class FileType { Input, Output, SafeOutput };

        // Partial Template Specialization
        template<FileType> class File;

        template<>
        class File < FileType::Input > {
        public:
            File( const std::string& filename ) : fin(filename) {

                if(fin.fail()) throw std::runtime_error("Error opening file: "+filename);
            };

            /** ...

            IFile& allows for syntax like
            fin>>a>>b>>c;
            */
            File& operator>>(int& a) {
                fin>>a;
                return *this;
            }

            /**...*/
            operator bool() {
                return !(fin.fail());
            }

            operator std::string() {
                return "Active";
            }

            // operator [data type]() {
                // code here
            //  return [object of type data type];
            // }

            friend File& getline( File& fin, std::string& line) {
                getline( fin.fin, line);
                return fin;
            }

            friend File& getrow( File& fin, std::vector<int>& rows);
            friend File& getmatrix( File& fin, std::vector< std::vector<int> >& table);

            ~File() { fin.close(); };
        private:
            std::ifstream fin;
        };  

        template<>
        class File < FileType::Output > {
            std::ofstream file;        
        public:

            File(std::string filename, size_t output_precision = 10) {

                file.open(filename);
                if(file.fail()) throw std::runtime_error("Error: cannot open file");

                file.precision(output_precision);

            };

            /*
            OFile& operator<<(int x) {
                file<<x;
                return *this;
            }
            */

            /*
            OFile& operator<<(const Point2D& p) {
                file<<p;
                return *this;
            }
            */

            File& operator<<(const std::vector<int>& v) {

                for(auto x : v) file<<x<<std::endl;
                return *this;
            }


            template<typename T>
            File& operator<<(const T& p) {
                file << p;
                return *this;
            }


            ~File() { file.close(); };

        };

    }

    #endif
```

Comment: Which parts are you having trouble with? Do you understand the concepts of [Stirling numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number) and [Chebyshev polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials)? What language are you using? What do you mean "recursive functions for partitions"?

Comment: So partitions are talking about integer partitions. So for example, if I have an integer n, say, 5. The partition is the set of positive integers that sum up to 5. {5}, {4,1}, {3,2}, {3,1,1}, {2,2,1}, {2,1,1,1}, and {1,1,1,1,1}. And I don't understand the concept of Stirling numbers or Chebyshev polynomials but my professor said we shouldn't need to in order to do the assignment.

Comment: Has he given you instructions on how to generate them, then, because if not, you're going to have to have at least *some* understanding...

Answer (score 2):

This is really several questions in one, so I will take it in parts.

## Partitioning

This is probably the hardest of these tasks, but it's pretty doable if you break it down.

What are all the partitions of a number `n`? The first number in each partition must be between 1 and n. Since we don't care about order, let's just always keep the numbers in descending order. So the first list of partitions looks something like this:

- `{n}`
- `{n-1, 1}`
- `{n-2, 2}`, `{n - 2, 1, 1}`
- `{n-3, 3}`, `{n - 3, 2, 1}`, `{n - 3, 1, 1, 1}`
- ...
- `{1, 1, ..., 1}`

But wait! We can say that more simply. That's just

- `[the set of partitions starting with n]`
- `[the set of partitions starting with n - 1]`
- `[the set of partitions starting with n - 2]`
- ...
- `[the set of partitions starting with 1]`

Which is really just all the partitions starting with `n - i` for all `i` between 1 and `n`. So, if we can find a way to get each group of partitions for each `i`, we can simplify things.

How might we do that? Well, if we think about it, we can realize that we can get every partition which starts with `n - i` pretty easily. Each partition is just `n - i` followed by a way to get numbers which add up to `i`... which is exactly what a partition is, so we've found our recursive case! We get all of our partitions by getting `n - i` followed by each of the partitions of `i`.

Now we just need a base case. That's pretty simple: we can just define the partitions for zero to be the empty set.

### Putting It All Together

So what does this look like?

```
vector<vector<int>> getPartitions(int number, int maxElement)
{
    if (number < 1) return vector<vector<int>>();
    vector<vector<int>> partitions;

    if (number <= maxElement) partitions.push_back({number});

    for (int i = number - maxElement; i < number; ++i)
    {
        // (recursively) get the partitions of `i`, with elements no larger than `n - i`
        auto partitionsForI = getPartitions(i, number - i);

        // add `n - i` to the front of all of those partitions
        for(vector<int>& partition : partitionsForI)
        {
            partition.insert(partition.begin(), number - i);
        }

        // add these new partitions to our list.
        partitions.insert(partitions.end(), partitionsForI.begin(), partitionsForI.end());
    }
    return partitions;
}
```

## Stirling Numbers

These are pretty similar. If you look at their respective Wikipedia pages, you can find recurrence relations for each kind:

### [First Kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind)

```
s1(n, k) = -(n - 1) * s1(n - 1, k) + s1(n - 1, k - 1)
```

### [Second Kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)

```
S2(n, k) = k * S2(n - 1, k) + S2(n - 1, k - 1)
```

And they have the same base cases: `S(0, 0) = 1`, `S(n, 0) = 0` and `S(0, n) = 0`.

So you could define a function to calculate them something like this:

```
int firstKindStirling(int n, int k) 
{
    if (n == 0 && k == 0) return 1;
    else if (n == 0 || k == 0) return 0;
    else return -(n-1) * firstKindStirling(n-1, k) + firstKindStirling(n-1, k-1);
}
```

and the one for the second kind would look very similar to that.

## Chebyshev Polynomials

It's not totally clear what the requirement is here. I'm going to assume it's to evaluate one at a point, not to come up with some expanded representation. It goes pretty much the same as the Stirling Numbers.

Again, [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) has a recurrence relation:

```
chebyshev(0, x) = 1
chebyshev(1, x) = x
chebyshev(n, x) = 2 * x * chebyshev(n-1, x)  -  chebyshev(n-2, x)
```

I assume you can figure out how to make that into a function. (Hint: basically all it takes is turning those left-hand sides into if statements, similar to the example above.)

Comment: Thank you so much this really helped. Visual Studio is giving me an error with this line though:
if (number <= maxElement) partitions.push_back({number});//issue is with the curly bracket before number. I think I need to change that to just (number); correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Your compiler might not support initializer syntax. You'll need to construct the vector manually if that's the case.

Comment: From what I'm reading in my book, it should have worked with push_back(number) since that's the value I'm trying to add to the end of the vector and number has already been declared. I'm not quite understanding what's wrong with it...

Comment: It's a vector<vector<int>>. You can't add an int to a vector<vector<int>> directly. The braces around it are a shortcut for a vector which contains the elements inside those braces.

Comment: I think my computer hates me. I added the code, for some reason I'm just not able to figure this out.