# java.lang.StackOverFlowError in computing Stirling number of the second kind while using BigInteger

Tags: java

My main goal is to compute the Stirling number of the second kind with an input of 1 to 500. Without using the BigInteger option/import, the code works flawlessly but the moment I use the said import, I encounter java.lang.StackOverFlowError because of BigInteger k (I tried converting it to d out of desperation).

Hope someone can help. And if possible, please point out other errors if you will spot any. Thank you!

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
try{
System.out.print("Please enter the r: ");
BigInteger n = sc.nextBigInteger();
System.out.print("Please enter the n: ");
BigInteger k = sc.nextBigInteger();

BigInteger constant= new BigInteger("0");
BigInteger result = new BigInteger("1");
BigInteger result2 = new BigInteger("500");

    int result3 = n.compareTo(result);
    int result4 = n.compareTo(result2);
    int result5 = k.compareTo(result);
    int result6 = k.compareTo(result2);
    int result7 = n.compareTo(constant);
    int result8 = k.compareTo(constant);



if (result3 == -1 || result4==1){
    System.out.println("n must be 1 to 500");
}
if (result5 ==-1 || result6 == 1){
    System.out.println("k must be 1 to 500");
}
else if (result7 == 1 && result4 == -1 && result8 == 1 && result6 == -1){
System.out.println("The answer is: " + StirlingFunction(n, k));
}
}

catch(InputMismatchException a){
    System.out.println("The input must be an integer.");
}
}


public static BigInteger StirlingFunction(BigInteger n, BigInteger k){
   BigInteger d= new BigInteger("0").add(k);
   BigInteger a = BigInteger.ONE;
   if (k.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) == 0 || k == n){
      return BigInteger.ONE;
   }

   else{
    BigInteger x = (StirlingFunction(n.subtract(a), d));
    BigInteger y = (StirlingFunction(n.subtract(a), k.subtract(a)));

   return k.multiply(x).add(y);

    }
}

}
```

[This is the result/output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFFPw.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revised to answer what was wrong.

```
k==n
```

is never true because they are different objects, so your code never hit its base case. Changing it to

```
`k.equals(n)`
```

made your code give the right answer quickly, with no error.

The following translated from the post at [Recursive functions for partitions, stirling numbers, and chebyshev polynomials of the first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049552/recursive-functions-for-partitions-stirling-numbers-and-chebyshev-polynomials) may or may not be helpful. I tried to keep things as close to that and as simple as possible, while pretty much emulating your code.

```
public static BigInteger StirlingFunction(BigInteger n, BigInteger k){
   if (BigInteger.ZERO.equals(n) && BigInteger.ZERO.equals(k)){
       return BigInteger.ONE;
   }
   //still here, not both zero
   if (BigInteger.ZERO.equals(n) || BigInteger.ZERO.equals(k)){
       return BigInteger.ZERO;
   }
   BigInteger x = StirlingFunction(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), k);
   BigInteger y = StirlingFunction(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), k.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
   //S2(n, k) = k * S2(n - 1, k) + S2(n - 1, k - 1)
   return k.multiply(x).add(y);

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The code works flawlessly but is there any possible way to compute large numbers like n=300 k=150? I tried using the said code but still, it doesn't compute large numbers

Edit: The code works for large numbers. But runs at a very slow pace. Any suggestion to speed up the pace of showing the output? Thank you very much!

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not know. I am wondering if that recursion would blow the call stack, in which case maybe the explicit formula would be better (though dividing by 150! seems like a crazy big number). Also probably worth using https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/space-and-time-efficient-binomial-coefficient/

Comment: Sure. Good news. Without any fast factorial tricks (except not using recursion), 150! took .29 seconds on https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/.